# Raw string always return 0

Tags: android

I have a id stored in a str like "R.raw.de3", and I need to recover its id in int form in order to set this on a MediaPlayer class, however any way that I tried this int id always return 0.

I already tried

```
rawIdStr =  "R.raw.de3"; or rawIdStr =  "R.raw.de3.mp3";
```

with

```
int rawId = getResources().getIdentifier(rawIdStr, "id", getPackageName());
```

or

```
int rawId = getResources().getIdentifier(rawIdStr, "raw", packageName);
```

and too

```
int rawId = R.raw.class.getField(rawIdStr).getInt(null);
```

and nothing, why this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the whole `"R.raw.de3"`, just the file name without the R and the resource type identifier.

Try

```
rawIdStr =  "de3";
int rawId = getResources().getIdentifier(rawIdStr, "raw", packageName);
```

Answer (score 0):

To open raw resources check out using this:

```
  Resources.openRawResource(R.raw.filename)
```

This will give you an input stream that you can pass to your media player.

For more information see:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Details are here: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource(int)